# Groovy: Why the "in" operator when used in maps of booleans has such a weird behaviour?

Tags: groovy, dynamic, contains

Basically this happens

```
def map =   [a:"Hello", b: "World", c: true, d: false]

println("a" in map) // true
println("b" in map) // true
println("c" in map) // true
println("d" in map) // false WHY????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator, or rather the [Membership Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_membership_operator) is represented by the `isCase` method, which was originally added for `switch` statements.

I can't tell you why they decided to implement it this way, but it is implemented like this for Maps:

`org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods#isCase(java.util.Map, java.lang.Object)`

```
    /**
     * 'Case' implementation for maps which tests the groovy truth
     * value obtained using the 'switch' operand as key.
     * For example:
     * <pre class="groovyTestCase">switch( 'foo' ) {
     *   case [foo:true, bar:false]:
     *     assert true
     *     break
     *   default:
     *     assert false
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param caseValue   the case value
     * @param switchValue the switch value
     * @return the groovy truth value from caseValue corresponding to the switchValue key
     * @since 1.7.6
     */
    public static boolean isCase(Map caseValue, Object switchValue) {
        return DefaultTypeTransformation.castToBoolean(caseValue.get(switchValue));
    }
```

If you want to be certain to check only the keys you need to write something like this `x in map.keys()`.